# Rollover as CSS Sprite

Tags: html, css

i create this slider and now i want to put some images in it and on hover that images should be in color.. (sprites)

```
<div class="client-wrapper ">
    <ul class="happy-clients clearfix ">
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 1">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 2">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 3">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 4">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 5">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 5">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 5">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="client 5">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That is my slider and i try to add this css but it don't work :

```
#test {
    height: 42px;
    width: 42px;
    background-image: url(http://img826.imageshack.us/img826/6568/homebi.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: top;
}
#test:hover {
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

Where do I need to add this ID or is there some other options..

Comment: Are each of those list items supposed to be their own sprite?

Comment: no..it is one sprite..

Comment: Well, you don't have a `#test` element for one thing... Typically for sprites would apply the same background image to multiple elements, but adjust the positioning of that image differently for each element to expose a different sprite on your image.

Comment: When i put this <li>
<div id="test"></div>
</li>
It gives me only one picture .. and i need all ..

Comment: That HTML seems to have nothing to do with your CSS, and the CSS seems to have nothing to do with the thread title. I'm confused. Maybe create a jsFiddle to show what you are actually trying to do. A simple sprite rollover is quite easy.

Comment: Ok, here is fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/mTXDU/68/ Here i have only one button but i need it all.. you will see what i mean..

Comment: What do you think about this.. http://jsfiddle.net/mTXDU/ But here is only one picture.. i need something like that just with different pictures..

Comment: You want them to show up in color on hover? Like a grayscale to color?